yt-dlp -- how to add ffmpeg conversion after download
I'm using a rather long yt-dlp command to download and convert the downloaded files into mp4 format. However, the resulting mp4 files sometimes cause problems. That's why I would like to add a ffmpeg conversion directly after download. At the moment, I am using the following command:
alias ytdl='cd ~/Desktop; function _ytdl(){ yt-dlp -o "%(upload_date>%Y-%m-%d)s %(title)+.100U [%(id)s]" --download-archive /Users/admin/Documents/bin/ytdl_archive.txt --merge-output-format mp4 --no-check-certificates $1;};_ytdl'

The --merge-output-format mp4 option may not be necessary anymore. Instead I would like to add something like this:
... | ffmpeg -i nnn.nnn nnn.mp4

Is there any way to combine this into an alias, while keeping the elaborate filename?
Thanks a lot for any help,
G.

But wait, yt-dlp doesn't write to stdout, does it?

Apparently -o - will have it write to stdout.

yt-dlp --exec {COMMAND} is your friend; I'd recommend you just write a script that takes one argument and uses that with ffmpeg -i …, but you can also piece together your ffmpeg command line the same way you can build output file names; for that, see man yt-dlp, and search for "output template".
